# LTC4041: disable DC/DC converter from an MCU

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet

How I can enable/disable an [LTC4041](https://www.mouser.pl/ProductDetail/Nexperia/74HCT00BQ115?qs=P62ublwmbi%2FXq3RQ1pBZXg%3D%3D) using an external P-MOSFET?

In a typical application, pin 4 (CHGENn) and pin 5 (BSTENn) are connected directly to GND. This configuration permanently enables the internal Backup Boost Converter and Supercapacitor Charger.

To turn off the system, pins 4 and 5 should be connected to a voltage above 1.2 V.

I am thinking of using the [BSS84](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuKfA.png) P-MOSFET transistor. R<sub>DS(on)</sub> = 10 Ω at V<sub>GS</sub> = -5 V.

[image]

I am thinking of using a Logic Gate ([74HCT00BQ,115](https://www.mouser.pl/ProductDetail/Nexperia/74HCT00BQ115?qs=P62ublwmbi%2FXq3RQ1pBZXg%3D%3D)) instead of the MCU as input control signal (MCU_CTR_5V).

[image]

//Edit: Reverse Q6 Drain-Source
[image]

Comment: Why can't you drive the pins directly from the MCU? And Q6 has drain and source reversed.

Comment: I want use Logic Gate as input.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to drive the pins from the micro controller directly if the MCU supports open drain and a pullup, no fet necessary.

If you used only the pullup,the EN pins would startup diabled with the pullup until the processor woke up and pulled the voltage down to enable the backup and supercapacitor charger.

If you wanted to invert the logic so the supercapacitor charger and backup were enabled on poweron without any MCU, then you could use a push pull output with a pulldown.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs1AWx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution. I removed one logic inverter based on NAND gate.

[image]